# Getting all possible combinations of a regular expression string

Tags: python, combinations, permutation

I have a regular expression: `ATG(C|G|A)(C|T)GA`

The above regular expression could take any form with only OR (`|`) special characters at any position in the string and any number of alphabets within the brackets.

I want to match all combinations of this string in a list:

```
ATGCCGA
ATGCTGA
ATGGCGA
ATGGTGA
ATGACGA
ATGATGA
```

I am unable to find any python library that could do this.

Answer (score 4):

You could take the cartesian product of the dynamic parts of the string using `itertools.product` then join with the other static parts of the string.

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> [f'ATG{i}{j}GA' for i,j in product('CGA', 'CT')]
['ATGCCGA', 'ATGCTGA', 'ATGGCGA', 'ATGGTGA', 'ATGACGA', 'ATGATGA']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion:

```
import collections
s = 'ATG(C|G|A)(C|T)GA'
def combos(d):
   r, k = [], None
   while d:
      if (c:=d.popleft()) not in '|()':
         k = (k if k else '')+c
      elif c == '|':
         if k:
            r.append(k)
         k = None
      elif c == '(':
         r = [v+(k or '')+i for i in combos(d) for v in (r if r else [''])]
         k = None
      else:
         if k:
            r.append(k)
         k = None
         break
   yield from ([i+(k or '') for i in r] if r else [k])

print(list(combos(collections.deque(list(s)))))
```

Output:

```
['ATGCCGA', 'ATGGCGA', 'ATGACGA', 'ATGCTGA', 'ATGGTGA', 'ATGATGA']
```